# Name of 80s sci-fi film involving scientists recording a persons memory

Tags: story-identification, movie

This film was made sometime the 80s I think and was concerned with scientists who developed some device that could be used to record memories. The main story was about one of the scientists dying and using the device to record her death. This resulted in the military getting involved. That is about all I remember but I remember it being a very good and thought provoking film that I would like to watch again. I just cannot remember what it was called though. Does anyone know what this movie is called?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The movie is [Brainstorm](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085271/). It wasn't memories though, it was sensations.

Yes, it was a great movie. Natalie Wood (playing Christopher Walken's wife) died during the time this movie was being made. Very sad.

Comment: Beat me by seconds... +1 anyway :)

Comment: Great! I just youtubed a few clips and that is exactly the film. Thanks!! Now I just have to find the DVD.